# I don't get why my run time is slower on the second sorting than the first?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Essentially, I know that the run time on the second time should be way slower than the first, however, sometimes when I run it the second time is way slower. I know it is not supposed to be that way, and I know the size of the array shouldn't affect it. I have no reason why and stop and end time shouldn't really matter since they are subtracted anyways. It may be just a dumb mistake, but I am new to programming so any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;

 class Main { 
      // Sort the Array
   public static void selectionSort( int[] array ) {          
     // Find the integer that should go in each cell of     
     // the array, from cell 0 to the end     
     for ( int j=0; j<array.length-1; j++ ) {
        // Find min: the index of the integer that should go into cell j.       
        // Look through the unsorted integers (those at j or higher)       
        int min = j;       
        for ( int k=j+1; k<array.length; k++) {
            if ( array[k] < array[min] ) {
                min = k;
            }
        }
        // Swap the int at j with the int at min        
        int temp = array[min];   
        array[min] = array[j];  
        array[j] = temp;     
      }
   } 

   public static void main ( String[] args ) {
    Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What size is your array?: ");
    int size = kbReader.nextInt();
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] values = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        values[i] = rand.nextInt(size);
    }

    System.out.println("Before: Not Sorted");
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    selectionSort( values );
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
    System.out.println("After: Sorted");

    //second time sorting it

    System.out.println("\nThis is the second time sorting: ");
    System.out.println("Before: Not Sorted");
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    selectionSort( values );
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
    System.out.println("After: Sorted"); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce: `10000: 26 ms / 21 ms`, `100000: 2065 ms / 2052 ms`, `200000: 8196 ms / 8178 ms` --- They all look very **equal** to me.

Comment: You do know that printing `Before: Not Sorted` before the *second* run is a lie, right? You know, since `values` is still sorted from the first run.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I'll change my wording on that part. The numbers you got were really interesting because sometimes I get 24 ms/78 ms.

Comment: Those are too small measurements, well within the tolerance of `currentTimeMillis()`. Try a larger array size, e.g. multiply by 10 to get 100 times the elapsed time, i.e. 2-3 seconds. Or use `nanoTime()` for more timing precision.